# No change in v4.master or css but still getting error

Tags: site-collection, records-management

Getting this error "Code blocks are not allowed in this file" when accessing http://portal.company.com/companyErecord/rcconsole.aspx

This is a brand new site collection created with Record Template. It uses built in v4 and CSS. There are NO modification to anything but we are getting "code blocks ...." error.

I tried couple of links but they did not solve my issue: social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/c83a82b1-52cc-43b5-90c2-78534973e2c0

social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/4fb1ba6b-0df1-42ca-ac07-785752173bd9

= = = error = = =

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Code blocks are not allowed in this file.

Source Error:

Line 41:      function showHideError()
Line 42:      {ULSs5K:;
Line 43:        var docIdEnabled = "<%= Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentId.IsFeatureEnabled(SPContext.Current.Site) %>";
Line 44:        var iprEnabled = "<%= Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.Records.IsInPlaceRecordsEnabled(SPContext.Current.Site) %>";
Line 45:        var errSpan = document.getElementById("errFeatureDisabled");

Source File: /companyErecord/rcconsole.aspx    Line: 43

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

= = = end of error = = =

So what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restore the v4.master to an earlier version.
http://yantriki.blogspot.com/2010/08/sp2010-v4master-page-changes-results.html

Comment: Thanks. It worked. So Masterpage must have been broken. Thanks